# Floated elements not floating properly

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

I have some images that are floated next to each other. I want a user to click on an element (in this case click on the "bio" button") to open a new div with text that would be floated next to the image.

I know that this can be done in theory like indicated here: http://jsfiddle.net/MGDTech/waq7x/1/.

```
li {display: block; float:left; background: #eee; margin: 20px; height: 80px; width: 80px;}
li.hide {display: none;}
```

But when I implement it in my beta wordpress site, it doesn't work and the text is floated below the image.

Here is the actual code: http://jsfiddle.net/MGDTech/GT36x/

```
.bio-button {font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif; font-weight: 600; font-size: 10px; letter-spacing: 1.5px; background: #fff; color: #2d2d2d; width: 44px; text-align: center; padding: 0px 0px 0px 3px; position: relative; top: -125px; z-index: 10; cursor: pointer; margin-top: 360px;}
.bio-button:hover {opacity: 0.5; zoom: 1; filter: alpha(opacity=50);}
.team-member {float: left; margin-right: 40px; }
.team-member .close {float: right;}
.team-member img {opacity: 0.5; zoom: 1; filter: alpha(opacity=50);}
.team-member img:hover {opacity: 1; zoom: 1; filter: alpha(opacity=100);}
.team-member h2, .team-member p, .team-member .bio-button {margin-left: 22px;}
.team-member h2 {font-size: 11px; font-weight: 300; line-height: 15px;text-transform: uppercase; color: #737373; letter-spacing: 2px; -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px;}
.team-photo p {font-size: 11px; font-weight: 300; line-height: 15px;text-transform: none; color: #737373; padding-top: 5px; -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px;}
.team-photo {float:left;  width: 50%;}
.team-text {display: none;float: left; width: 50%; height: auto; padding: 25px 0px 0px 0px; font-size: 12px; }
```

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

css and divs are tricky.

The simple solution to the problem you describe above it to move the div.team-text to before the div.team-photo.
That will create a problem for you with the close button - I would move that one inside the div.team-photo.

Comment: Thanks Fredrik. That is a step in the right direction! I knew it was something easy! I still have problems related to the sizing but I can figure that out.